# Error: Unknown duplicates value on record with id

Tags: salesforce, integration, apex-code, apex, apex-data-loader

I'm trying to `Upsert` the data to Account object using an external tool, Everything works fine but `Salesforce` is throwing error for few records when `upserting`.

I was doing the upsertion process using the external id field. Except external id field no other field is having a unique constraint.

I'm getting the following error -

> SF_ERROR: DUPLICATE_VALUE
>
> OBJ: Account - duplicate value found: unknown duplicates value on record with id: 001***********

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you try to update same record in your import source? Imagine telling Salesforce to "update record 123 some value = 7" and few lines below in the import file - "update record 123 with some value = 5". It will have no idea which value should "win" and so it'll throw an error back at you. Alternatively - are you really upserting by that ext. id field? You have to explicitly use it in the mapping or by default it'll try to upsert by Id. Are the updates that succeed really hitting the old rows or are they creating new ones?

Comment: make sure your external id is unique and in the data you are getting the field which is mapped to external id does not have repeated values..

Comment: Hi @eyescream, I'm usperting with the external id field and it unique too. And the source does'nt have any duplicates on External id.

Comment: What do you get if you search your import file (database, whatever) for whatever is the value of that ext. id field on the Account from the error? And is there any chance you have triggers or workflow rules that modify these ext. ids during insert?

Comment: this is happening because your trying to create Salesforce contact multiple times with same email and data

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your trying to create Salesforce contact multiple times with same email and data

Answer (score 0):

It's silly but this was happening to me because SFDC considers 'NULL' as a unique value...  Mostly because Excel converted 'NULL' to text and was trying to bring in the literal word 'NULL'.